# Could I use C# to invoke Output as XML feature of SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, xml

MSSQL Server could return query result as XML format. My question is, could I use C# to invoke this function directly? I just want to generate XML without using any serialization or some other methods which used in traditional C# codes.

Thanks
SuT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [ExecuteXmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executexmlreader.aspx)

From [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316701):

```
   using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("data source=(local);initial catalog=pubs;.....")) {
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM authors FOR XML AUTO, XMLDATA", cn);

        XmlReader xmlr = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader();
        xmlr.Read();
        while(xmlr.ReadState != ReadState.EndOfFile) {
                    Console.WriteLine(xmlr.ReadOuterXml());
        }                       
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`SqlXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlxml.aspx) class is what you need to use. However, given the nature of SQL connections, the XML data will still be serialized and deserialized under the hood. (Objects can only be used in the same memory space. As soon as application boundaries are crossed, some form of serialization will be required)